# How to pause a video while navigating using Bottom Bar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I'm building a Flutter app that has a bottom navigation bar with multiple tabs. The home screen tab contains a video player, and I want to pause the video playback when navigating away from the home screen.

My app structure contains a Bottom Navigation. and in these navs i have a HomeScreen which the video player is in. then in this page I separated the video player from the rest of the layout also to fetch the videos and controll pageview.builder.

so in my video widget i did this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:ramadan/routes.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:cached_video_player_plus/cached_video_player_plus.dart';

class VideoTile extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoTile(
      {super.key,
      required this.video,
      required this.snappedPageIndex,
      required this.currentIndex});
  final dynamic video;
  final int snappedPageIndex;
  final int currentIndex;

  @override
  State<VideoTile> createState() => _VideoTileState();
}

class _VideoTileState extends State<VideoTile> {
  // late VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
  late CachedVideoPlayerPlusController _cacheController;
  late Future _initializeVideoplayer;
  bool _isVideoPlaying = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    _cacheController = CachedVideoPlayerPlusController.networkUrl(
      Uri.parse(
        widget.video['url'],
      ),
      httpHeaders: {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
      },
      invalidateCacheIfOlderThan: const Duration(minutes: 60),
    );
    _initializeVideoplayer = _cacheController.initialize().then((value) async {
      await _cacheController.setLooping(true);
      _cacheController.play();
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    _cacheController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentRoute = Get.currentRoute;

    (widget.snappedPageIndex == widget.currentIndex &&
            _isVideoPlaying &&
            currentRoute == AppRoutes.home)
        ? _cacheController.play()
        : _cacheController.pause();
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _initializeVideoplayer,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return InkWell(
                onTap: () => {
                  _isVideoPlaying
                      ? _cacheController.pause()
                      : _cacheController.play(),
                  setState(() {
                    _isVideoPlaying = !_isVideoPlaying;
                  })
                },
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  children: [
                    CachedVideoPlayerPlus(_cacheController),
                    IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          _cacheController.play();
                        },
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.play_arrow,
                          color: Colors.white
                              .withOpacity(_isVideoPlaying ? 0 : 0.5),
                          size: 60,
                        ))
                  ],
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return Container(
                color: Colors.pink,
              );
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

so now when i use the bottom nav and navigate to other routes like profile or explore, i want the player to pause. how do i do that?

Comment: Instead of instantiating the `CachedVideoPlayerPlusController` in `_VideoTileState` itself, you could provide the option to pass it in. Then, you can create an instance of the controller where you create you bottom nav bar, and call `_cacheController.pause()` in the `onTap` callback

Comment: @anqit that would work but i came up with a neat solution. i used visibility detector package and worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I was about to delete this post but i thought this might help someone. just incase.

so what i did is that i used a package called `visibility_detector` and wrap the video tile widget with it.

```
VisibilityDetector(
      key: Key('videoTile_${widget.currentIndex}'),
      onVisibilityChanged: (visibilityInfo) {
        if (visibilityInfo.visibleFraction == 0) {
          _cacheController.pause();
          setState(() {
            _isVideoPlaying = false;
          });
        } else {
          _cacheController.play();
          setState(() {
            _isVideoPlaying = true;
          });
        }
      },
     // child: your future builder here
     );
```

so what this does is it detects if it's on the screen, if not it will pause the video.